# Convert Sql table field input into HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

my Database table field look like this

```
id - name  - school      - subjects                    -  marks

1  - Adam  - Highschool  - Geography,physics,math      -  60,50,40

2- - Jhone - elementry   -  Math,Language,Geography     - 90,20,10
```

the php file should convert this values into html table using boot strap

my expected reslut to be like this

```
Hello Jone! this is your results
Math : 90
Language : 20
Geography : 10
```

I tried different methods like convert the result into array but it did work with me will.

one of them are

```
<?php
$shop = array( array("title"=>"rose", "price"=>1.25 , "number"=>15),
               array("title"=>"daisy", "price"=>0.75 , "number"=>25),
               array("title"=>"orchid", "price"=>1.15 , "number"=>7) 
             ); 
?>

<?php if (count($shop) > 0): ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($shop))); ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($shop as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row); ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

any advice

thanks

Comment: *I tried different methods* - what you tried? where is the code?

Comment: I will update my post sorry

Comment: First it is not a good database design, second write the code blocks you have tried.

Comment: I am not sure if the comment is adequate but I would strongly suggest you rethink your database normalization. It would probably not be a bad idea to separate the subjects and marks from this table as now your subjects and marks are too heavily reliant on the way data is being represented. So maybe put them all as separate entries in a different table and join them using student id's. Or at least json encode or something equivalent.

Comment: I would concur with @apriede. Use a separate table called marks with columns id, studentid, subject, mark and join them when displaying results.

Comment: the problem is we get the data form a form that send us the information like this, this is why

Comment: i get the information form a form and then process it into php file, 
the admin can click on + to add more subject and mark 

then into php file 
`
 $subjects = $_POST["subjects"];
 if ($subjects[0]!=""){
  $subjects_list = implode( '<br/>', $subjects);
 }
 $marks= $_POST["marks"];
 if ($marks[0]!=""){
  $marks_marks = implode( '<br/>', $marks);
 }`

Comment: @marvillous Well just because you get the data in a certain way from a form doesn't mean you have to shove it right into the database. You can process it and create a nice and tidy database structure. Of course it is up to you but if in the future you might need to get average marks or get the number of students enrolled in a certain class it will become a nightmare.

Comment: u shold normalise your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be great to normalize your data and to avoid any comma separated lists in your database. However you can achieve this very easily using `explode()`:

Input:

```
mysql> select * from marks;
+----+------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
| id | name | school      | subjects                | marks    |
+----+------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
|  1 | Adam | High School | Geography,physics,math  | 60,50,40 |
|  2 | Jone | Elementary  | Math,Language,Geography | 90,20,10 |
+----+------+-------------+-------------------------+----------+
2 rows in set
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test') or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $query = "SELECT * FROM marks";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $subject = explode(',',$row['subjects']);
            $marks = explode(',',$row['marks']);
            echo 'Hello '.$row['name'].'! This is your results:';
            echo '<table>';
                foreach($subject as $k=>$s){
                    echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$s.'</td>
                        <td>'.$marks[$k].'</td>
                    </tr>';
                }
            echo '</table>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Output is table for each user:

```
Hello Adam! This is your results:
Geography   60
physics     50
math        40

Hello Jone! This is your results:
Math        90
Language    20
Geography   10
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is what I really need.
do you have any suggestion  to normalize my data ?

the problem is that I use jquery function with (+) mark to add new row, and then I send the information to php file like this 
`$subjects = $_POST["subjects"]; if ($subjects[0]!=""){ $subjects_list = implode( '<br/>', $subjects); } $marks= $_POST["marks"]; if ($marks[0]!=""){ $marks_marks = implode( '<br/>', $marks); }`
so what is your advice

Comment: I think the best way is to insert the form result into 2 tables one for student info and the other for subjects and marks. I will use`LAST_INSERT_ID() ` to make the result row have one filed for the student id ( to connect student id with the results list).. now the question is how could I create in results table for each student 3 rows for example in the same time.. ( they take the information from post method in my previous comment.)

Comment: subjects must be in totally separated table. Then you need need additional table (many-to-many) in order to store all marks from all sublects for each user `(user_id, subject_id, mark)`. At the end you need to change your PHP scripts accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is was a big help to understand how to sot my data wright.

But how could I insert an array of data into many rows

Comment: don't do implode, but make foreach loop over received `$_POST["subjects"]` array and do multiple inserts.